# specific host at user mariadb

Tags: triggers, mariadb, privileges, sql-grant

currently I have mariadb user with host like this

```
'userdb'@'10.148.0.0/255.255.240.0'
```

and grant like this

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'userdb'@'10.148.0.0/255.255.240.0' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*21E60721C392B0B98F8E387DDA480376C04B42B5'
```

but when from application we got error message like this

```
TRIGGER command denied to user 'userdb'@'10.148.0.0/255.255.240.0' for table 'tclmuser'
```

and then i check the definer from trigger is same like user.
so this is issue come from host at user ?

Comment: I don't know that I've ever seen host specified in host/subnet form. Typically a form of one of the examples shown at [their documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/#granting-user-connections-from-remote-hosts).

Comment: me too, as long i know about host specified like this `192.168.%.%`